# How to convert binary data,created by C#.net into video file, in java

Tags: java, c#, android, .net

Ok.
Here is the problem.

I am trying to send a couple of videos from My PC to an Android device.
To do this, I found two methods.
1) Through TCP/IP.
2) By Using Database.

I don't know much about Socket programming that's why I choose database option.

Then I created a program in C#.NET, to convert my video file into binary data and save it into the database.
I am using MS SQL Server for Database.

I saved my data in VARBINARY(max) datatype.

After that, I tried to read the data from the android device but I am unable to read it.

I am new to java that's why I started with reading a small file, a pdf file and I successfully did it, By the way, i used the JAVA for converting pdf file to binary and saving it in the database.

But I am failed to read the video file.

The only result I got is a "Movie.mp4" file size of 104KB.

So after lots of searching, I found that there is an endian problem, short endian and long endian.

Now my question is what should I do to read the file correctly. or how can I accomplish this?

Note it is mandatory, and easy for me to use the C# on the PC's end. Because I know it more than java.

Here is my Code in Java on the Android side.

```
  Connection myConn = null;
    Statement myStmt = null;
    ResultSet myRs = null;

    InputStream input = null;
    FileOutputStream output = null;

    try {

        String userName = "abc";
        String password = "abc123";
        String db = "save";
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ABC;"
        + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + userName + ";password="
                + password + ";";

        // 1. Get a connection to database
        myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        // 2. Execute statement
        myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT RaportPlik FROM Raporty WHERE RaportID = '1'";
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

        // 3. Set up a handle to the file
        File theFile = new File(path, "Movie.mp4");
        output = new FileOutputStream(theFile);

        if (myRs.next()) {

            input = myRs.getBinaryStream("RaportPlik");


            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer);
            }

       query.setText("\nSaved to file: " + theFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    } catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "error in connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        query.setText("Error is " + exc);
    }
    finally {
        if (input != null)
        {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            close(myConn, myStmt);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This the Code which i used to convert the video file to binary

```
public static void databaseFilePut(string varFilePath)
    {
        byte[] file;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(varFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            }
        }

        using (SqlConnection varConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ABC;Initial Catalog=save;Integrated Security=True"))
        using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raporty (RaportPlik) Values(@File)", varConnection))
        {
            varConnection.Open();
            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
            sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
            varConnection.Close();
        }



    }
```

Comment: I would not use conversion from long to int you might lose information there.
Have you tried to receive this file from C# ? to see if everything is okay after putting it in the db? When i was doing class projects from C# to java etc i didnt have problems like that.

Comment: Yes i did and there Were no problems.